# "Difference failed" error when using difference tool with point layers as input and overlay in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-processing, geoprocessing, differences

Is it possible in QGIS 3.16 to use the geoprocessing tool *"Difference"* with point layers as input and overlay?

The documentation seems to indicate that it is. However, when I do a test with very simple layers, it gives a *GEOS geoprocessing error*:

> difference failed

The input layer has 10 points, and the overlay has 6 points - these 6 points are in the exact same location as 6 points in the input layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the same error. How to solve the problem:

1. Apply a (small) [buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html?#buffer-vectors) of the same size around both point layers.
2. Run the Difference tool on these buffers.
3. From the resulting buffers (the difference), get the [centroids](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#centroids).

And here you are with the difference-points you want.

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks so much.  Do you know if this is a bug in this version of QGIS or not?

Comment: I used QGIS 3.20, so the version does not matter. Probably its simply not made for point-geometries - however, it works with lines.

Answer (score 0):

An option to use difference function with point geometries is using QGIS expressions with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html?#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with this expression:

```
difference (
    $geometry,
    aggregate('points_2', 'collect', $geometry
))
```

*Expression used on layer `points_1` (10 red dots) with difference from `points_2` (6 blue triangles) results in 4 points (black rings) of `points_1` that don't overlap `points_2`:*
[image]